# async Task IEnumerable XElement

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asynchronous

I'm not sure whether this is possible, so any input/help would be appreciated.

I have the following in a class below, (all caching removed here):

```
public static class MasterXMLWeatherClass
{
public static async Task<IEnumerable<XElement>> WorldWeather(string id)
{
XDocument doc = await Task.Run(() =>  XDocument.Load(string.Format("http://urladdress?key={0}&feedkey={1}&format=xml&q={2}&tp=6&extra=isDayTime", sPartnerID, sLicenseKey, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(id))));
var getAllWeatherData = from weatherData in doc.Descendants("data")
                                    select weatherData;
return getAllWeatherData.AsEnumerable();
}
}
```

Then in another class I have 4 methods that gets the values from the above, problem is I get the following error in all:

> 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task>'
>   does not contain a definition for 'Descendants' and no extension
>   method 'Descendants'  accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task>'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

```
var doc = MasterXMLWeatherClass.WorldWeather(id);
```

`var displayCurrentConditions = (from wd in doc.Descendants("current_condition")` -This is the line of code throwing the error.

But if I then change:

```
var doc = MasterXMLWeatherClass.WorldWeather(id);
```

to

```
var doc = await Task.Run(()=> MasterXMLWeatherClass.WorldWeather(id));
```

and change below to

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<DisplayCurrentConditions>> CurrentConditions(string id)
```

The errors go away and I get an error in the interface, which I then have to change.

Finally I get no errors in my domain layer, but I then get errors in my UI layer

The errors are just bubbling up.

Is there another way of doing this?

Code additions

Interface

```
Task<IEnumerable<DisplayCurrentConditions>> CurrentConditions(string id);
```

UI

```
public PartialViewResult pvHomePageWeatherDetails(string id)
{
var currentConditions  =  _IGWC.CurrentConditions(cleanText).FirstOrDefault();
return PartialView();
}
```

Comment: What happens when you change it to `var doc = await MasterXMLWeatherClass.WorldWeather(id);`? I don't think there is a need for `Task.Run`.

Comment: Hi Daniel I get the following error in UI controller. 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Web.Domain.WorldWeather.DisplayCurrentConditions>>' 
does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault' and no extension method 'FirstOrDefault' accepting a first argument of type 
'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Web.Domain.WorldWeather.DisplayCurrentConditions>>' 
could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: It's worth noting that `Task.Run(Action)` returns a `Task` and `Task` obviously doesn't have a `Descendants` property.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't forget the `await`?

Comment: The error starts on this line var currentConditions               =  _IGWC.CurrentConditions(cleanText).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: This is getting too confusing. Please show your real code. I don't see `_IGWC.CurrentConditions` in your question.

Comment: This is what I have put var doc = await MasterXMLWeatherClass.WorldWeather(id);

Comment: In my controller in the UI I have the following: public PartialViewResult pvHomePageWeatherDetails(string id)
{
var currentConditions  =  _IGWC.CurrentConditions(cleanText).FirstOrDefault();
return PartialView();
} I did not put the partialview in original code.